# IIS Url Rewriting with parameter

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor, url-rewriting

I would like to use IIS Url Rewrite but the sites I came across did not explain in-depth what do I have to do and why, there was just code to "copy-pase" and I would rather know how am I making tings work.

I have this code in my hosting site:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
             </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have two pages. Default.cshtml and room.cshtml which must take parameter to display properly (room.cshtml?roomId=[id here]). What I would like to achieve is:
1) Get rid of .cshtml on both these pages. 
2) Make second page look like example.com/room/[id here] 
3) When someone goes to example.com/room without id parameter, I would like him to get redirected to example.com/room/1

Comment: This sounds like it should be done via MVC routing rather than Url Rewriting. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: @Cal279 My site is not made in MVC concept but it is one as asp.net web-page, so I do not know if that would work.

Comment: So it doesn't have a 'RouteConfig' class under App_Start?

Comment: @Cal279 I have used this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/187/more-flexible-routing-for-asp-net-web-pages